# how to get the correct associated xml tag names for data with different key values in the same text file

Tags: xml, vb.net

my problem is that different sets of data with different sets of values have different header tags even though everything is in the same text file. I  have code which identifies the headers based on key value. How would I go about converting my text file into xml. Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myText As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path & Filetxt)
    Dim ary As String() = myText.Split(vbCrLf)
    Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(Path & FileXml, Encoding.ASCII)
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    writer.Indentation = 4
    writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
    writer.WriteStartElement(RootEle)

    For x As Integer = 0 To ary.Length - 1
        Writestudent(writer, ary(x))
    Next
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
    writer.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub Writestudent(ByVal wr As XmlWriter, ByVal str As String)
    '-----setting the delimiter
    Dim strDelimiter As String = ComboBox1.Text

    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please select a delimiter")
    End If

    If strDelimiter = "T" Then
        strDelimiter = vbTab
    ElseIf strDelimiter = "S" Then
        strDelimiter = " "
    ElseIf strDelimiter = "C" Then
        strDelimiter = ","
    ElseIf strDelimiter = "SC" Then
        strDelimiter = ";"
    End If

    Dim ary As String() = str.Split(strDelimiter)

    '------Classes-------

    Dim strRecordType As String = Nothing

    Dim strReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(IT01_FilePath)
    strRecordType = strReader.Substring(0, 4)

    Select Case strRecordType
        Case "IT01"
            '              do something???()


            Dim tmpRecIT01 As New IT01(strReader)

            tmpRecIT01.RecordIdentifier

         Case "IT02"
             '              do something???()


    End Select

End Sub

End Class
```

> example of what I want my xml to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" standalone="yes"?>
<Data_Xml>
  <DataTable>
    <ref></ref>
    <order></order>
    <number></number>
    <ID></ID>
    <code></code>
    <contact></contact>
  </DataTable>   
</Data_Xml>
```

> example of IT01 file

```
Public Class IT01

    Private strref As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal strLine As String)
        InitializeComponent(strLine)
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponent(ByVal strLine As String)

        Dim strTemp As String = Nothing

        '-- Record Indentifier
        strTemp = Strings.Mid(strLine, 1, 1).Trim
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strTemp) = False Then
            strref = strTemp
        End If

    End Sub
```

> sample from txt file:

255 75  2   I   I000002 PH +12 12345678FX

Comment: My text file is Tab separated and my xml is not wrote yet as I am looking for the headers from the ITO1 file for my xml tags

Comment: sorry by xml header tag names I mean ref, order etc but those headers are not in my file but in the IT01 FILE

Comment: OK, so what is the significance of the `strRecordType` referred to in `strRecordType = strReader.Substring(0, 4)`? Does that mean there is more than just the column headers in the `IT01_FilePath` file?

Comment: I was trying that to see if it identified my file record but I am not sure if I was even on the right track

Comment: no its compiled @AndrewMorton

Comment: Do I have this correct: you have a file with tab-separated values and although there are no headers in that file, you know which column is which value, e.g. the first column like "255" is always the "ref", the sixth column like "+12 12345678FX" is always the "contact"?

Comment: yes thats exactly it. and the code I have in IT01 will validate the code contents and also identify the headers. so I would like to know how to use this code in my other file.sorry for it being so unclear

Comment: I have re-worded my question and given a more general view of what I am trying to do

Comment: So the values in each column might mean something different from one line to the next, and what the columns represent is determined by the first column?

Comment: yes one line could mean something different to the next. what it reppesents is determined by the IT01 file.

Comment: How different are the lines? For example, could one represent the price of tea for the last 12 months, the next line be an error message, and the one after that the co-ordinates of a square? ~Or~ is each line related but perhaps with different options? Could just one class sensibly be used for every variation?

Comment: they are all related but different so need to use different classes. the classes for each are alredy related. do you know how to solve my problem? thanks

Comment: I think I might be getting a better idea of the problem now, but I do have to do work as well ;) In the meantime, I think that [VB.NET XML Serialize a List of Inherited Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44189552/1115360) could be what you need.

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt mean that in a rude way. I just meant do you have an idea of what my problem is, thats all. Thanks I'll take a look

Comment: I had a look at that sample but I am still a little confused as to how to apply it to my problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to do something manually, which is actually very easily done by .NET.

Please read this carefully and save yourself a lot of time in the future;

https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/315703/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-basic-net-or-visual

In short, you should create a class called student, like so;

```
Public Class Student
    Public Property Ref As String
    Public Property Order As String
    Public Property Number As String
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Code As String
    Public Property Contact As String
End Class
```

And then;

```
Dim p As New Student()
p.Ref= "Jeff"
p.Code= "A"
p.Contact = "Price"

Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType)
x.Serialize(Console.Out, p)
```

Please invest some time in this, for this is much quicker and better than doing everything manually. The other way around, is also possible and very easy, see the article.

Comment: thank you for your answer but the file IT01 is like that as it is used for other code work. while your information proved informative, it is not th answer to the question I am asking. Is my question unclear if so I will edit it. thanks

Comment: Study my example for that is literal what you ask. You ask; I want to convert a text file to an xml file. how do I use a class I have in another file to created my xml header tag names. My example shows you how you can write the headers tags in a XML file. You can just copy the class, you don't even have to type it...

Comment: sorry I have made it unclear. so my class in my other file has my headers and tags already created  but how do I use that file to transfer the headers so as they are the tags of the xml file